# Limiting Ord to letters only

Tags: pascal

I'm trying to create a simple Crypting method for a school project, the idea is to change a character by increasing it's ascii with a user entered number then replacing it back.
So my problem is when I do it, it works, but it also includes symboles like %$! ...etc.
What I want to do is to limit the Ord function to letters only, For example if the user entered the number 100 but there's only 26 letters in the alphabet, it will keep looping over and over through that 26 till it reaches the 100th.
Hope I'm clear enough lol
Here's what I have so far, a part of a whole code:

```
Procedure Crypting( Var cryptFile : Text; tempVar2 : String; pNumber: Integer);
Begin
  Writeln('Enter P : ');
  Readln(P);
    Reset( cryptFile );
    For i:= 1 to length(tempVar2) do
            Write(Chr(Ord(tempVar2[i])+P));
End;
```

Comment: You can't limit the operation of a built-in function, which `Ord()` is; the best you can do is "wrap" it in your own code so that you don't call it at all except when the value is within the set you wish to allow.

Comment: And how's that possible in my case?

Comment: Think about it in terms of your question: *If the value is not a letter, do not call Ord()*.  Or, rather, *If the value is a letter, call Ord()*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are looking to implement the [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher).

First, you need to use an `if` statement to check if the current character is a letter or not. If so, you transform it; if not, you leave it as it is.

Second, it is not enough to simply add `P` to the character code. Although it works for `A` and `P = 3`, producing `D`, what will happen for `Y` and `P = 3`? You need to use [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) so you get `Y → Z → A → B`.

Third, in programming, it is important to structure your code well and refactor it properly. Currently, you mix input and transformation. You should keep these separate. If you create a `Caesar` function, you can use it every time you need to perform the Caesar cipher.

If we also need to support both capital and small letters, it is better to use a `case` construct instead of an `if .. else if .. else` construct.

Putting it all together:

```pascal
function Caesar(const S: string; N: Integer): string; // slow
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  for i := 1 to Length(S) do
    case S[i] of
      'A'..'Z':
        Result := Result + Chr(Ord('A') + (Ord(S[i]) - Ord('A') + N) mod 26);
      'a'..'z':
        Result := Result + Chr(Ord('a') + (Ord(S[i]) - Ord('a') + N) mod 26);
    else
      Result := Result + S[i];
    end;
end;
```

This function works, but is not optimal from a performance point of view, since you need a heap allocation for every iteration. It is better to allocate the result string once and then only fill it:

```pascal
function Caesar(const S: string; N: Integer): string;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(S));
  for i := 1 to Length(S) do
    case S[i] of
      'A'..'Z':
        Result[i] := Chr(Ord('A') + (Ord(S[i]) - Ord('A') + N) mod 26);
      'a'..'z':
        Result[i] := Chr(Ord('a') + (Ord(S[i]) - Ord('a') + N) mod 26);
    else
      Result[i] := S[i];
    end;
end;
```

A complete example:

```pascal
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

function Caesar(const S: string; N: Integer): string;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(S));
  for i := 1 to Length(S) do
    case S[i] of
      'A'..'Z':
        Result[i] := Chr(Ord('A') + (Ord(S[i]) - Ord('A') + N) mod 26);
      'a'..'z':
        Result[i] := Chr(Ord('a') + (Ord(S[i]) - Ord('a') + N) mod 26);
    else
      Result[i] := S[i];
    end;
end;

var
  s: string;
  N: Integer;

begin

  Writeln('Please enter a string to transform:');
  Readln(s);
  Writeln('Please enter shift size:');
  Readln(N);
  Writeln;
  Writeln('Result: ', Caesar(s, N));
  Writeln;
  Writeln('Thank you for using this program! Have a nice day!');
  Writeln('Press Return to exit.');
  Readln;

end.
```

(The precise program structure depends on the kind of Pascal you are using -- there are many different kinds of Pascal.)

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of console application output.]

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, but I didn't quite understand how I could apply this to my code in order to for an example, change this line ' Hello world ' to its equivalent after crypting it?

Comment: Tbh I'm still studying and thats still a bit out of my reach !

Comment: So I've been doing some tweaks and stuff, and it works exactly as I wanted it ! But one question tho, can it be applied to a whole text file? not just a line, like let's say there's 10 lines in a text file, and it ciphers it line by line

Comment: @FirasBlouza: Great! :)

Comment: I kept trying to make it cipher a whole text, but I end up ciphering the last line only :|

Comment: The user have the choice to choose if he wants to crypt a single line or crypt the whole file, the single line now works more than perfect, but the whole file ( multiple lines inside ) end up outputting the last line only. I hope you could help me with that also ! it's the last step to finish the program :D

Comment: @FirasBlouza: I don't think we can do that here. As you discovered when you took the [StackOverflow tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), StackOverflow is "all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat." Since this question (about differentiating between letters and non-letters) has been answered, this question should be considered "case closed". But you are welcome to create a new question if you need help with something else (like your new problem).

Comment: Noted, I'll post a new question